# How to obtain HTML code of images in ADOBE XD?

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, mask

Newbie here!
So I want to take this Html code right here..
File:

Use the brain on this as a mask https://xd.adobe.com/view/8686ddde-88a2-4e15-b6c1-9648aa81fa71-d3d5/

But I cannot figure out how to string adobeXd into Html/CSS/JavaScript for the life of me.
Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant HTML code? Where is your JavaScript attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to obtain HTML/CSS/JavaScript code directly from Adobe XD. You can try to save those images in your local desktop such as screenshot and embed it in your website. I believe there are many websites that teaches you how to embed images in a website. One of them is https://www.w3schools.com/. Hope this answers your question.